# Which Class in mongodb using the values from spring.data.mongodb

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, mongorepository

I am trying to understand a spring project which uses MongoDB drivers to connect to a db.
The `application.properties` file has the following properties defined:

```
spring.data.mongodb.database=${db.name:demo}
spring.data.mongodb.auto-index-creation=false
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://some-connection-string
```

And I see two relevant pieces of code in the project:

- `Application.java`

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCaching
@EnableScheduling
@ComponentScan({ "com.paans.*" })
@PropertySource("classpath:routes.properties")
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

   public static MongoTemplate _mongoTemplate;

public static void main(String[] args) {
       SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
   }

@Bean
   public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate(MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory, MongoMappingContext context) {
       MappingMongoConverter converter = new MappingMongoConverter(new DefaultDbRefResolver(mongoDbFactory), context);
       converter.setTypeMapper(new DefaultMongoTypeMapper(null));
       MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory, converter);
       mongoTemplate.setReadPreference(ReadPreference.nearest());
       _mongoTemplate = mongoTemplate;
       return mongoTemplate;
   }
}
```

- `MongoConfiguration.java`

```java
@Configuration
public class MongoConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;
    @Autowired
    MongoConverter mongoConverter;
    @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
    public void initIndicesAfterStartup() {

        MappingContext<? extends MongoPersistentEntity<?>, MongoPersistentProperty> mappingContext = this.mongoConverter.getMappingContext();

        if (mappingContext instanceof MongoMappingContext) {
            MongoMappingContext mongoMappingContext = (MongoMappingContext) mappingContext;
            for (BasicMongoPersistentEntity<?> persistentEntity : mongoMappingContext.getPersistentEntities()) {
                Class<?> clazz = persistentEntity.getType();
                if (clazz.isAnnotationPresent(Document.class)) {
                    IndexResolver resolver = new MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver(mongoMappingContext);
                    IndexOperations indexOps = mongoTemplate.indexOps(clazz);
                    resolver.resolveIndexFor(clazz).forEach(indexOps::ensureIndex);
                }
}}}}
```

Now, I am trying to understand the execution sequence of this code and which piece of code is actually picking up the properties set up in `application.properties`. Any help ?

Comment: None of that code. The Spring Boot auto configuration for Spring Data MongoDB is using that.

Comment: Is there an annotation that triggers it? - I have added the annotations of my main file in the question.

Comment: No as stated that is the spring boot autoconfiguration. Spring Boot detects MongoDB and the existence of Spring Data MongoDB and loads some additional configuration classes.